# How to format response text in to table format in google hangouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

Developed a Hangouts bot for auto reply.
Need a help here folks where I need to print a response as table in hangouts as per the requirement but as of now my bot is just returning the plain json text please help me if I need to show response in a tabular format.
I tried of using goolge slides to format but I'am not sure how to make use of it.
and it may be helpful if any one suggest the node(**node-red**) used to format the text on client side.
 made a try with **md2gslides** node.

**sample json obj:-**

```
{"template":{"type":"generic","content":[{"h5":"My Features"},{"table":{"headers":["XXX","XXX"],"rows":[["XXXX","XXXXX"],["XXX","XXXXXXX!"],["XXX","XXXXX"]]}}]}}
```

but I need show as a table on google hangouts as a response.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you point out how the output format should look like? A regular HTML table?

Comment: Thank for quick reply Frank.                                                                                     Yes it should look like a html table and it should return a table based on the command/request on hangouts.                                                                                                                            Example:If I request for  Features it should return a table with 3 columns and 2 rows based on response.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered same question, and, according to current documentation, 
no HTML entities are on cards allowed except listed https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards#card_text_formatting 
and those formatting applies to simple text messages: 
https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic.

I've just used monospace block in place of table.